# Unable to consume message from queue through jmeter(amqp consumer sampler)

Tags: jmeter, rabbitmq, amqp, producer-consumer

I tried to consume a message with queue name,exchange and routing key through jmeter but observed the below error

> 2019-11-06 14:53:29,326 ERROR c.z.j.p.a.AMQPConsumer: Failed to
>   initialize channel java.io.IOException: null
>               at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:106)
>   ~[amqp-client-3.6.1.jar:?]
>               at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:102)
>   ~[amqp-client-3.6.1.jar:?]
>               at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:124)
>   ~[amqp-client-3.6.1.jar:?]
>               at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclare(ChannelN.java:844)
>   ~[amqp-client-3.6.1.jar:?]
>               at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclare(ChannelN.java:61)
>   ~[amqp-client-3.6.1.jar:?]
>               at com.zeroclue.jmeter.protocol.amqp.AMQPSampler.initChannel(AMQPSampler.java:90)
>   ~[JMeterAMQP.jar:?]
>               at com.zeroclue.jmeter.protocol.amqp.AMQPConsumer.initChannel(AMQPConsumer.java:339)
>   ~[JMeterAMQP.jar:?]
>               at com.zeroclue.jmeter.protocol.amqp.AMQPConsumer.sample(AMQPConsumer.java:64)
>   [JMeterAMQP.jar:?]
>               at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622)
>   [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
>               at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546)
>   [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
>               at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486)
>   [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
>               at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253)
>   [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_191] Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error;
>   protocol method: #method(reply-code=406,
>   reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg
>   'x-dead-letter-exchange' for queue '' in vhost
>   '': received none but current is the value 'dead-letter' of
>   type 'longstr', class-id=50, method-id=10)
>               at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:67)
>   ~[amqp-client-3.6.1.jar:?]
>               at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:33)
>   ~[amqp-client-3.6.1.jar:?]
>               at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:361)
>   ~[amqp-client-3.6.1.jar:?]
>               at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:226)
>   ~[amqp-client-3.6.1.jar:?]
>               at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:118)
>   ~[amqp-client-3.6.1.jar:?]

So, tried to consume messages only with routing key and exchange key(without queue name) but for which, i am getting the below error.

> 2019-11-06 15:14:46,072 ERROR c.z.j.p.a.AMQPConsumer: Failed to
>   initialize channel java.io.IOException: null
>               at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:106)
>   ~[amqp-client-3.6.1.jar:?]
>               at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:102)
>   ~[amqp-client-3.6.1.jar:?]
>               at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicConsume(ChannelN.java:1119)
>   ~[amqp-client-3.6.1.jar:?]
>               at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicConsume(ChannelN.java:1087)
>   ~[amqp-client-3.6.1.jar:?]
>               at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicConsume(ChannelN.java:1071)
>   ~[amqp-client-3.6.1.jar:?]
>               at com.zeroclue.jmeter.protocol.amqp.AMQPConsumer.sample(AMQPConsumer.java:73)
>   [JMeterAMQP.jar:?]
>               at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622)
>   [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
>               at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546)
>   [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
>               at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486)
>   [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
>               at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253)
>   [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_191] Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error;
>   protocol method: #method(reply-code=404,
>   reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no previously declared queue, class-id=60,
>   method-id=20)
>               at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:67)
>   ~[amqp-client-3.6.1.jar:?]
>               at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:33)
>   ~[amqp-client-3.6.1.jar:?]
>               at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:361)
>   ~[amqp-client-3.6.1.jar:?]
>               at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicConsume(ChannelN.java:1117)
>   ~[amqp-client-3.6.1.jar:?]

Could you please guide us on how to consume message for a queue which has a dead letter exchange configured in JMeter?

Comment: To my understanding, it is pretty clearly tells you to provide it a dead letter exchange name: "inequivalent arg 'x-dead-letter-exchange' for queue '' in vhost '': received none but current is the value 'dead-letter' of type 'longstr'".

Comment: I tried to change the exchange name to dead-letter but its giving different error. I need to understand how we make the changes on jMeter AMQP consumer sampler

Comment: "I tried to change the exchange name to dead-letter" - I don't think that is what it expects you to do. You have to provide exactly this parameter: 'x-dead-letter-exchange'

Comment: Anyone who knows how to provide this parameter: 'x-dead-letter-exchange' in the Jmeter AMPQ Publisher. Any screenshot.